# Effect/action on root link in a collapsible menu inactive - just the effect - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a collapsible menu, generated dynamically, like this

```
<div id="mobile">
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="index.php?id=12">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="index.php?id=24">Approach</a>
            <ul class="subnavi">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.php?id=24">How we work</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.php?id=25">Who we are</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.php?id=26">Knowledge</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="index.php?id=14">Solutions</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="index.php?id=15">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

here is the code to collapse a submenu, with jQuery :

```
$('#mobile #navigation > li:has(ul) + a').on("click",function() {
    $(this).find('ul').show().end().siblings().find('ul').hide();
    return false;
});
```

My problem is that once I click the Approach menu link, I activate the "Approach" link. How can I do to activate only the .show() API, without triggering the link.

To be more specific, if I click on "Approach" I don't want to go to that page, I just want the submenu to collapse.

Is this making any sense? if so please give me a hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is wrong, use this :

```
$('#mobile #navigation > li:has(ul) > a').on("click",function(e) {
    $(this).siblings('ul').show().end().closest('li').siblings().find('ul').hide();
    e.preventDefault()
});
```

I have changed `+ a` to `> a` since the `a` is a children of the `li`.

I have also changed `.find('ul')` to `.siblings('ul')`

I have added `.closest('li')` before the last `.siblings()`.

http://jsfiddle.net/tagmx/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $("a").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Check this http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/ for event.preventDefault();